How can I not trigger GuildRoleCreate event by adding a bot?
const botMember = await role.guild.members.fetch(executor.id).catch(() => null);
            if (botMember && botMember.user.bot) {
                return;
            }

So Im trying not to trigger this GuildRoleCreate event if user adds bot to a server but I cant make it work. Can someone guide me thru how can I do it. bots create a role when joining the server and this event triggers also same GuildRoleDelete when any bot gets kicked my bot counts it as user kicked the bot.

After Looking At The GuildRoleCreate Event Implementation, I Think It May Not Be Possible To Detect That
link: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/main/packages/discord.js/src/client/actions/GuildRoleCreate.js

Thanks for reply already solved but it took me a while.. Ive done   if (role.tags && role.tags.botId) {             console.log(`Role deletion ignored as it was caused by the removal of bot ${role.tags.botId}`);             return;         } and this solved my problem. Works on Guildrolecreate and delete events if event was  triggered by removing and adding bott.
